# Is there an opportunity to stop GitLab Dependency Scanning job in pipeline if there are found high or critical vulnerabilities?

Tags: security, gitlab, gitlab-ci, dependency-management

I have include Dependency Scanning gitlab template in my .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
include:
  - template: Security/Dependency-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml
```

Now I want to break job if there are some critical or high vulnerabilities are found. Is there is such configuration to do it?